# .NET Deployment on lower version framework machines

Tags: c#, .net, deployment

I use VS2010 to create a project and when I deploy it in a machine with a lower version of .NET framework it gives me an error:

[image]

Typically that would require the user to go search for the framework, or download it from an internet location.

I want to give the user, an option to automatically download the framework file as I **cannot add it to the existing package**. Where can I get started?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the installer you can include the .net installation as a prerequisite. either directly or allow user to download the version from the internet. Please note that the .net 4 has a Client version that is smaller than the full version.

refer to the following links:

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eh4aaa5.aspx
2. http://msmvps.com/blogs/haarongonzalez/archive/2007/04/09/772757.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the direct answer Joseph!